# formatting time in R error

Tags: r, posixct

I have a `Time` column in my `df` with value `1.01.2016 0:00:05`. I want it without the seconds and therefore used `df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%d.%m.%Y :%H:%M", tz = "Asia/Kolkata")`. But I get NA value. What is the problem here?

Comment: It doesn't like the colon in front of the `%H`. In your example, is it 0 hours and 5 minutes?

Comment: @mysteRious now i get `2016-01-01 00:00:05` after removing the colon. The time is 0 hours, 0 minutes, and 05 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there are two things working here: the storage of a time object (`POSIXt`), and the *representation* of that object.

The string you present is (I believe) not a proper `POSIXt` (whether `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt`) object for R, which means it is just a character string. In that case, you can remove it with:

```
gsub(':[^:]*$', '', '1.01.2016 0:00:05')
# [1] "1.01.2016 0:00"
```

However, that is still just a string, not a date or time object. If you parse it into a time-object that R knows about:

```
as.POSIXct("1.01.2016 0:00:05", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "Asia/Kolkata")
# [1] "2016-01-01 00:00:05 IST"
```

then you now have a time object that R knows something about ... and it defaults to *representing* it (printing it on the console) with seconds-precision. Typically, all that is available to change for the console-printing is the precision of the seconds, as in

```
options("digits.secs")
# $digits.secs
# NULL
Sys.time()
# [1] "2018-06-26 18:21:06 PDT"
options("digits.secs"=3)
Sys.time()
# [1] "2018-06-26 18:21:10.090 PDT"
```

then you can get more. But alas, I do know think there is an R-option to say "always print my `POSIXt` objects in this way". So your only choice is (at the point where you no longer need it to be a time-like object) to change it back into a string with no time-like value:

```
x <- as.POSIXct("1.01.2016 0:00:05", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "Asia/Kolkata")
x
# [1] "2016-01-01 00:00:05 IST"
?strptime
# see that day-of-month can either be "%d" for 01-31 or "%e" for 1-31
format(x, format="%e.%m.%Y %H:%M")
# [1] " 1.01.2016 00:00"
```

(This works equally well for a vector.)

Part of me suggests convert to `POSIXt` and back to string as opposed to my `gsub` example because using `as.POSIXct` will tell you when the string does not match the date-time-like object you are expecting, whereas `gsub` will happily do something wrong or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `asPOSIXlt`:

```
> test <- "1.01.2016 0:00:05"
> as.POSIXlt(test, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="Asia/Kolkata")
[1] "2016-01-01 00:00:05 IST"
```